# FabricJS lines have different stroke offset

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS to render a set of lines to my canvas, these lines originate from the same coordinates with the same settings (except for the stroke width). The code I am using to draw 4 lines looks like this

```
this.canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 50, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 40,
  selectable: true,
  originY: 'top',
  originX: 'left'
}))

this.canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 50, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 20,
  selectable: true,
  originY: 'top',
  originX: 'left'
}))

this.canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 50, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'orange',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  selectable: true,
  originY: 'top',
  originX: 'left'
}))

this.canvas.add(new fabric.Line([50, 50, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'green',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  selectable: true,
  originY: 'top',
  originX: 'left'
}))
```

which results in the following output:
[Draw lines result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp8ii.png)

As you can see the lines have an offset of their strokewidth to the left and the bottom which causes them to render incorrectly. Is there a way to automatically remove said offset or do I need to manually calculate an offset? For simple shapes like lines this is not really a problem, but with complex polygons this becomes cumbersome.

I have added the example in a [codepen which can be viewed here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXmKoe)

The weird part is when using the native canvas implementation, all goes as it is supposed to as demonstrated in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKWJgd)

Comment: All you can do is change the position of line, here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzjYQo)

Comment: This is what I would like to prevent I am importing different shapes from different sources (svg, canvas) and I don't want to recalculate every single point

Comment: Then put origin to center, here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKmKwe)